# Personal Finance Manager

Tags: android, finance

I am looking for an application to run on **Android**, to help track my income and expenses across several accounts - similar to [MyUniverse](https://www.myuniverse.co.in/home.aspx) or [Mint](https://www.mint.com/).

Whilst both those applications do all as required, they're too complex to use on a day-to-day operation. I am looking for a more easier to use UI, and preferably one capable of automatically tracking my accounts.

Comment: Do you want to pay for it? What OS? (Android, iOS?) Does it need to be compatible across OS? Do you want reporting? Do you want it to be automatic?

Comment: Android would be better. Automatic would be better

Comment: Perhaps I could suggest PocketBook for automatic tracking of income/expense. Although I am not sure what banks/regions they support. Another Android application I have used is "MyBudgetBook".

Answer (score 1):

**GNUCash**

[GNUCash](https://www.gnucash.org/) has the following benefits:

1. Free for personal and business use;
2. Runs on Android, OSX, Linux and Windows;
3. Reports, Graphs and other functions are inbuilt;
4. Cross Platform sync (not natively, use Dropbox etc.)

Other functions it supports are:

- Double-Entry Accounting
- Stock/Bond/Mutual Fund Accounts
- Small-Business Accounting QIF/OFX/HBCI Import, Transaction Matching
- Scheduled Transactions Financial Calculations

You can read up on the documentation [here](https://www.gnucash.org/docs.phtml), and see more of the features [here](https://www.gnucash.org/features.phtml).

Comment: Abu_Bua - I edited your answer to be a little more descriptive - it is pending approval. For a little advertisement, I did a *real basic* "What is" on GNUCash: https://michaelnancarrow.com/2017/12/15/gnucash-its-awesome/ - I agree with you, GNUCash is a good option for OP!